# Datastax driver - limit columns and fetch columns range

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

We want to move from Thrift to DataStax driver to use our Cassandra.
In our ring we have some keyspaces and column-families.

Some column-families are "regular" RDBMS style, but some are "wide rows".

In our API we allow parameters as

`int limit` - to limit number of columns

`int rows` - to limit number of rows

`String from` - to indicate from which column to fetch the data

`String to` - to indicate until which column to fetch the data

Currently, in Thrift, we use `org.apache.cassandra.thrift.SliceRange.SliceRange(ByteBuffer start, ByteBuffer finish, boolean reversed, int count)` as follows:

```
SliceRange range = new SliceRange(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(fromColumn), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(toColumn), false, limit);
predicate.setSlice_range(range);
//...
slices = connection.multiget_slice(list, parent, predicate, consistencyLevel);
//parse slices data internal code...
```

in DataStax I started writing code:

```
TableMetadata tableMetadata = cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace(Metadata.quoteIfNecessary(keyspace)).getTable(Metadata.quoteIfNecessary(columnFamily)); 
Where selectWhere = QueryBuilder.select().from(tableMetadata).where(QueryBuilder.in("key", keys));
Statement statement = selectWhere.limit(rows).setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.valueOf(consistencyLevel));
ResultSet rs = session.execute(statement);
JSONObject fullJson = new JSONObject();
for (Row row : rs){
    JSONObject rowJson = new JSONObject();
    ColumnDefinitions cd = row.getColumnDefinitions();
    for (ColumnDefinitions.Definition def : cd.asList()){
        String columnName = def.getName();
        if ("key".equals(columnName)){
            continue;
        }
        rowJson.put(columnName, row.getString(columnName));
    }
    fullJson.put(row.getString("key"), rowJson);
}
return fullJson;
```

This seems to work for the "regular RDBMS style" column-families. But how do I limit the columns in the case of "wide-rows"? should I also use the limit clause? like this:
    `selectWhere.limit(limit)`

How do I tell datastax to return columns only in a certain range?
In the CFs with "wide-rows" if I use CLI to fetch data I get those results:

```
=> (name=myColumn1002432758, value=, timestamp=1437569115004000)
=> (name=myColumn1008916971, value=, timestamp=1437571455894000)
=> (name=myColumn1009257972, value=, timestamp=1437571311603000)
=> (name=myColumn1009735430, value=, timestamp=1419755102812000)
=> (name=myColumn1010271493, value=, timestamp=1437570712913000)
=> (name=myColumn1010783846, value=, timestamp=1419754313304000)
=> (name=myColumn1011325540, value=, timestamp=1437569756587000)

....

Returned 1560 results.
Elapsed time: 87 msec(s).
```

I've searched the web and tried a lot but couldn't find working example.

Please advise.

Cassandra details:

cqlsh> show version
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.13 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]

Using Datastax driver for java dse-java-driver-core-1.4.2.jar

Java 7

If need more details let me know.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
    cqlsh> describe table OFFLINE_1.XXXX;

```
CREATE TABLE "XXXX" (
key text,
column1 text,
value text,
PRIMARY KEY ((key), column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
comment='' AND
dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=1 AND
index_interval=128 AND
read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
default_time_to_live=0 AND
speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
compression={'chunk_length_kb': '64', 'sstable_compression': SnappyCompressor'};
```

Comment: For the wide row table you would just restrict the row count per partition which could be done setting the limit on the select statement.

Comment: thanks. 
what about getting the range (from, to)?

Comment: To select data for a particular range within a partition in CQL you provide a where clause against a clustering column. You haven't shared your data model so it will be hard to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: you may find this tool useful http://www.sestevez.com/sestevez/cassandradatamodeler/

Comment: @phact, what do you mean by "my data model"? I shared the output from CLI when I use get command on some key.
I'd love to share more details, please be more specific what do you mean.
Thanks.

Comment: Data model == table definition in cql

Comment: couldn't get definition using CLI.
getting this output:

WARNING: CQL3 tables are intentionally omitted from 'describe' output.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4377 for details.

Via DBeaver I see that there's only 1 column defined:
column name: key
Data Type: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
Ordinal position: 1
Key type: PRIMARY

Comment: Please type `describe table <keyspace name>.<table name>;`  in cqlsh and paste the result in the question above.

Comment: Added table description, thanks.
However, the important data is not stored in the "column1" or "value" columns, but in dynamically added columns (wide-rows).